# How to Compile/Build Telegram Source Code in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, telegram

Is there anyone who can help me to compile Telegram source?

I cloned the source from GitHub and imported it to Android Studio
i use android studio latest version 2023.1.1 and try any version of ndk
this is example of error i got :

```
Executing tasks: [:TMessagesProj_App:assembleAfatDebug, :TMessagesProj_App:assembleAfatDebugUnitTest, :TMessagesProj_App:assembleAfatDebugAndroidTest, :TMessagesProj:assembleDebug, :TMessagesProj:assembleDebugUnitTest, :TMessagesProj:assembleDebugAndroidTest, :TMessagesProj_AppHockeyApp:assembleAfatDebug, :TMessagesProj_AppHockeyApp:assembleAfatDebugUnitTest, :TMessagesProj_AppHockeyApp:assembleAfatDebugAndroidTest, :TMessagesProj_AppHuawei:assembleAfatDebug, :TMessagesProj_AppHuawei:assembleAfatDebugUnitTest, :TMessagesProj_AppHuawei:assembleAfatDebugAndroidTest, :TMessagesProj_AppStandalone:assembleAfatDebug, :TMessagesProj_AppStandalone:assembleAfatDebugUnitTest, :TMessagesProj_AppStandalone:assembleAfatDebugAndroidTest] in project C:\Users\username\Desktop\Telegram


> Configure project :TMessagesProj
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"The option setting 'android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true' is deprecated.\nThe current default is 'false'.\nIt will be removed in version 9.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.\nYou can resolve this warning in Android Studio via Refactor > Migrate BuildConfig to Gradle Build Files","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"DSL element 'dexOptions' is obsolete and should be removed.\nIt will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.\nUsing it has no effect, and the AndroidGradle plugin optimizes dexing automatically.","sources":[{}]}

> Configure project :TMessagesProj_App
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"DSL element 'dexOptions' is obsolete and should be removed.\nIt will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.\nUsing it has no effect, and the AndroidGradle plugin optimizes dexing automatically.","sources":[{}]}

> Configure project :TMessagesProj_AppHockeyApp
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"DSL element 'dexOptions' is obsolete and should be removed.\nIt will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.\nUsing it has no effect, and the AndroidGradle plugin optimizes dexing automatically.","sources":[{}]}

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Telegram\TMessagesProj_AppHuawei\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':TMessagesProj_AppHuawei'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.huawei.agconnect'.
   > API 'android.registerTransform' is removed.
     
     For more information, see https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin-api-updates#transform-api.
     To determine what is calling android.registerTransform, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':TMessagesProj_AppHuawei'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 789ms
```

please help.

Comment: This seems like a question for whatever GitHub project that you are using. We can not know what could be the issue with a random project from the internet.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/721855

Comment: It looks like a version mismatch.  It looks like Gradle in your Android Studio is too new for the project you are trying to build.  Specifically, the "com.huawei.agconnect" plugin for Gradle is trying to use a Gradle API that has been removed.  Read the link in the output.

Comment: As a general rule, before you ask a "please help me" question, you should try (harder!) to understand your problem yourself.  Read all of the error messages, look at the resources that they link to.  And try to understand what they are saying.  (That is all that >>I<< did to come up with my diagnosis.  I've never used Android Studio or Gradle in my life.  I just know how to read an error message ...)